# dplyr function for measuring mean and proportion of a particular value in different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset, `df`, and I wanted to measure some column-wise indicators. I want to extract the proportion of instances of value 1 in my **var4** column, and also measure the mean of **var3**, and finally return them as text. I need to do that by creating a function and I did try with my basic understanding of R and `dplyr`, but I got errors. I would appreciate if anyone could let me know a better way to formulate my function.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
ch   <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 20, replace = TRUE)
cls  <- sample(c("CLASS ONE", "CLASS TWO"), size = 20, replace = TRUE)
var1 <- sample(1:20, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
var2 <- sample(20:40, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
var3 <- sample(40:60, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
var4 <- sample(c(0,1), size = 20, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(ch, cls, var1, var2, var3, var4, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

funcA <- function(col1, col2) {
    # for measuring percentage of col1== 1 in length of col1 
    select1   =  df %>% select(col1) %>% filter(col1 == 1)
    prop1     =  (length(selected$col1)/length(df$col1))*100
    # for measuring median of col2
    select2   = df %>% select(col2) 
    avg       = mean(select2)
    # pasting them in texts
    paste("The percentage of value 1 in", "col1", "is: ", prop1)
    paste("The mean value of", "col2", "is: ", avg)
}


funcA(var4, var3)
```

Comment: (1) Never have a function that _assumes_ there is a variable it uses externally, always pass it explicitly. There are few exceptions, and you are not in a clear exception to that. (2) You cannot do `df$col1` when `col1` is a character vector as an indirect reference to a column, use `df[[col1]]` instead. (3) `selected` is never defined, that's a typo. (4) Similar to #2, I have no idea why you would use base-R indexing `selected$col1` (which should be `selected[[col1]]` if it existed) and then `df %>% select(col2)`, they are for the same purpose, not sure why you do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option that also uses `glue`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

set.seed(1)
ch   <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 20, replace = TRUE)
cls  <- sample(c("CLASS ONE", "CLASS TWO"), size = 20, replace = TRUE)
var1 <- sample(1:20, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
var2 <- sample(20:40, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
var3 <- sample(40:60, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
var4 <- sample(c(0,1), size = 20, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(ch, cls, var1, var2, var3, var4, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

funcA <- function(col1, col2) {
  
  select1 <- df %>% 
    reframe(
      prop = prop.table(table({{col1}})),
      avg = mean({{col2}})
    )
  
  out <- list(
    prop = paste0("The percentage of value 1 in ", as.list(match.call())[[2]], " is: ", unique(select1$prop)),
    percent = paste0("The mean value of ", as.list(match.call())[[3]], " is: ", unique(select1$avg))
  )
  
  glue::glue_collapse(out, sep = "\n\n")
  
}

funcA(var4, var3)
#> The percentage of value 1 in var4 is: 0.5
#> 
#> The mean value of var3 is: 51.1
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt. I used your code but I ran to an error regarding `reframe`. 
`Error in reframe(., prop = prop.table(table({ : could not find function "reframe"`. I've loaded all required libraries, `tidyverse`, `glue` and `dplyr` but I don't know why it reurned an error.

Comment: You probably have an older version of `dplyr`. You can change `reframe` to `summarise`.